# Translating, anuvaad karana or अनुवाद करना

Tags: android, android-studio

When you make translations do you use English Characters or The cultures native characters? So for example would I Put "Anuvaad karana" or "अनुवाद करना" instead of "Translating" when translating into Hindi?

```
English TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EnglishTxt);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Translating");

Hindi TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HindiTxt);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Anuvaad karana");

HindiC TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HindiCTxt);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("अनुवाद करना");

 Random rand = new Random();
        String random = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
        tv.setText(random);
```

Thanks in Advance.

P.S The code is just an example it's not actually anything.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the culture's native characters in translation, so the people who will use the app and switch to there own language would understand the context.

for example (good) would be in Arabic جيد